# Access enum from another file within a static function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums

A.swift:

```
struct ApiRequest {
    static func getUrl() {
        // MyEnum.oneDay ---> Use of undeclared type 'MyEnum'
    }
}
```

B.swift:

```
public enum MyEnum: String {
    case oneDay = "1d"
    case sevenDays = "7d"
    case thirtyDays = "30d"
}
```

How do I access `MyEnum.oneDay`?

Comment: Have you declared `MyEnum` inside class B ?

Comment: Make sure that A.swift and B.swift belongs to the same module

Comment: What's the problem with declaring `let enumValue = MyEnum.oneDay` in `getUrl()` function?

Comment: @DanielKrom: his MyEnum is defined as public, so it can be accessed everywhere

Comment: @QuangHà it's still need to be imported if it's from different module :)

Comment: If its declared inside class `B` you need to access like `B.MyEnum`

Comment: @DanielKrom: so he needs to import...

Comment: @QuangHà tell him that, not to me, this is why I'm asking if they are in the same module...

Comment: Guys, I am new to Swift from Android. How do you see if the files are in different modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a class B like this,

```
class B {
    public enum MyEnum: String {
        case oneDay = "1d"
        case sevenDays = "7d"
        case thirtyDays = "30d"
    }
}
```

you can access it in class A like this,

```
class A {
    struct ApiRequest {
        static func getUrl() {
            print(B.MyEnum.oneDay)
        }
    }
}
```